# Request compression WCF 4 with IIS 7.5

Tags: wcf, .net-4.0

I know that WCF in .net 4 supports compression of responses out of the box (when using IIS 7.5 and a HTTP based binding). How can compression of **requests** be achieved with WCF 4 and IIS?

Comment: Not sure if browsers can even do this, but can be wrong.